# Saving an image as 120 Height x Proportionate Width - VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Is there an easy way to save an image as a set 210px Height but the width will be proportionate. Eg. If the image is naturally 420 x 600 then it would resize/save as 210 x 300. The code I'm using is VB and is currently set to save it as 210x210..

```
    Dim returnImage As System.Drawing.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\domains\example.com\httpdocs\catalog\images\" & imageFilename)
    Dim thumb As System.Drawing.Image = FixedSize(returnImage, 210, 210)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is maintain the aspect ratio, this is the code I use:

```
Public Function ScaleImage(ByVal OldImage As System.Drawing.Image, ByVal TargetHeight As Integer, ByVal TargetWidth As Integer) As System.Drawing.Image

    Dim NewHeight As Integer = TargetHeight
    Dim NewWidth As Integer = NewHeight / OldImage.Height * OldImage.Width

    If NewWidth > TargetWidth Then
        NewWidth = TargetWidth
        NewHeight = NewWidth / OldImage.Width * OldImage.Height
    End If

    Return New Bitmap(OldImage, NewWidth, NewHeight)

End Function
```

Comment: Very helpful thank you. I don't require the IF statement as I want the images to be 210 height but no restriction on width so I took that out. Many thanks again!